# Property 'jasmineMatches' is missing in type 'x'

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine-node

After `ng test`

Expected output: i get pass/fail on x amount of tests.

Actual ouput:

```
ERROR in src/app/todo-data.service.spec.ts(19,45): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Todo[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected<Observable<Todo[]>>'.
  Type 'Todo[]' is not assignable to type 'ObjectContaining<Observable<Todo[]>>'.
    Property 'jasmineMatches' is missing in type 'Todo[]'.
```

In my todo class i don't have a jasminematches property, but this might not be the root problem.

todo.ts:

```
export class Todo {
  id: number;
  title: string = '';
  complete: boolean = false;

  constructor(values: Object = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, values);
  }
}
```

todo-data.service.spec.ts

```
import {TestBed, async, inject} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {Todo} from './todo';
import {TodoDataService} from './todo-data.service';

...

  describe('#getAllTodos()', () => {

    it('should return an empty array by default', inject([TodoDataService],
      (service: TodoDataService) => {
      expect(service.getAllTodos()).toEqual(<Todo[]>[]);
    }));

...
```

todo-data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Todo } from './todo';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

...

export class TodoDataService {

  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

  getAllTodos(): Observable<Todo[]> {
    return this.api.getAllTodos();
  }

...
```

Please advise how to start deconstructing this error in order to write a correct test.

Answer (score 1):

Your getAllTodos function returns an observable and not an array of todos. I think this is why an error occurs. Therefore I think you should write your test differently:

```
service.getAllTodos().subscribe(todos => {
  expect(todos).toEqual([])
});
```

Also (if you haven't already) you probably want to provide a a stub (mock) for your api service. You should test this service in it's own file.

In your testfile below describe but before you make your testBed (or in a separate file from which you can import it):

```
const dummyTodos = [];

const mockApiService = {
  getAllTodos() {
    return Observable.of(dummyTodos);
  }
};
```

In your TestBed.configureTestingModule add the line:

```
providers: [{provide: ApiService, useValue: mockApiService}],
```

You can also decide to change the value of the dummyTodos in your tests to check for different responses.

Answer (score 1):

I came to the same conclusion of the previous poster. Your initial test assertion is comparing a pending Http request (represented as an observable stream with a single observable) to the expected response of an empty `Todo[]' array.

In the code snippet below, the `.subscribe` method activates the observable stream. Placing it inside of a `fakeAsync` zone simulates the passage of time in the same way that an asynchronous `Http` request behaves. Since the test assertion is inside the `subscribe` block, you are now dealing with a completed observable stream and are able to access the contents of the stream, i.e., `Todo[]`.

```
it('should return an empty array by default', fakseAsync(inject([TodoDataService],
  (service: TodoDataService) => {
      service.getAllTodos().subscribe(success => {
        expect(success).toEqual(<Todo[]>)
      });
  ))
);
```

One behavior in your test that I don't quite understand is your `TodoService` appears to delegate `Http` handling to an `ApiService` that returns `Observable<Todo[]>` and your `TodoService` also returns `Observable<Todo[]>`. If there's a meaningful layer of abstraction between these two services, then I'd defer to the testing method with a `MockApiService` outlined in the initial answer.

Alternatively, you could collapse your `ApiService` and `TodoService` into a single level and make additional assertions about the expected behavior (the mechanics of testing/simulating the `Http` backend will depend on whether you are using the `Http` methods in `@angular/http` or `@angular/common/http`).